# PWA offline check - TypeError: Network request for [start_url] threw an error: Failed to fetch

Tags: progressive-web-apps, workbox

https://songbook.app/en?standalone=true - this page URL is already in cache - workbox still throws an error that it can't fetch it.

[image]

I've tried to add it to runtime cache using axios get request and also directly adding it to cache like this:

```
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        caches.open('sb-runtime-cache-v1').then(function(cache) {
          cache.match('/en?standalone=true').then(function(response) {
            if (!response) {
              cache.add('/en?standalone=true')
            }
          })
        })

        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js', {
          scope: '/'
        })
      })
    }
```

Could you help to figure out how to fix this issue?

Previously I've added this url to cache using axios get request and it worked, now it's broken, I believe after google "improved offline check".
If I use preCaching - error disappears, but I need it in runtime cache because I need to refresh response in cache after user signed in to app.
LMK if have to provide more details.